# How to show a div element on mouse hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-hover

I need to show a `div` when a list element is hovered over, sort of like a drop-down menu.

I already have a way to do this with jQuery which is what I want, but the problem is that when I move mouse away from the list (`li` element), the `div` disappears. I want to be able to move the mouse from the list element to the div and be able to interact with the elements within the div.

This would be solved with a click function but I don't want to use click because the elements on the div will contain anchor links that when click will take users down the page, therefore you can see how a click function that shows and keep the div is not a good idea, unless I can find a way to close the div when its contents (anchor links) are clicked.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .nav-item-dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    /* other styles ... */
  }
</style>

<div class="nav-wrap">
  <ul>
    <li id="nav-item1" class="nav-item-wrap">Services</li>
    <li id="nav-item2" class="nav-item-wrap">Projects</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="nav-item-dropdown nav-item1-dropdown">
  <!-- Drop-down nav contents for services (title and image) wrapped by anchor link goes here -->
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#nav-item1').hover(function() {
      $('.nav-item1-dropdown').toggle();
    });
    jQuery('#nav-item2').hover(function() {
      $('.nav-item2-dropdown').toggle();
    });
  });
</script>
```

I want to be able to move the mouse from the list element (`.nav-item-wrap`) to the `div` (`.nav-item-dropdown`) and be able to interact with the elements within the `div`. I don't want the `div` to disappear when I move the mouse away from the list element that triggered it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.toggle()` method simply toggles the visibility of elements. In your code they do well what they are for.  In your case,  instead of toggle use `.show()` and  `.hide()` like below. You need additional `class` to hide `div` when load.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#nav-item1').hover(function() {
    $('.nav-item1-dropdown').show();
    $('.nav-item2-dropdown').hide();
  });
  jQuery('#nav-item2').hover(function() {
    $('.nav-item2-dropdown').show();
    $('.nav-item1-dropdown').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.nav-item-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  /* other styles ... */
}

.yourClass {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-wrap">
  <ul>
    <li id="nav-item1" class="nav-item-wrap">Services</li>
    <li id="nav-item2" class="nav-item-wrap">Projects</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="nav-item-dropdown nav-item1-dropdown yourClass">
  div1
  <!-- Drop-down nav contents for services (title and image) wrapped by anchor link goes here -->
</div>
<div class="nav-item-dropdown nav-item2-dropdown yourClass">
  div2
  <!-- Drop-down nav contents for services (title and image) wrapped by anchor link goes here -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. What you have works but I want the div to disappear (be hidden) when I move the mouse away from the div. As it is now, it stays visible even when scrolling down the page. I need to be able to put mouse on the div and interact with its contents but have the div disappear on mouse out.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In that case handle mouseleave() when mouse out. Another option is mousewheel event.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery('#nav-item1').mouseover(function() {
         $('.nav-item1-dropdown').show();
      }); 
      jQuery('#nav-item2').mouseover(function() {
         $('.nav-item2-dropdown').show();
      });
   });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. What you have works but I want the div to disappear (be hidden) when I move the mouse away from the div. As it is now, it stays visible even when scrolling down the page. I need to be able to put mouse on the div and interact with its contents but have the div disappear on mouse out.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use something like this for showing and hiding the div

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-wrap">
  <ul>
    <li id="nav-item1" class="nav-item-wrap">Services</li>
    <li id="nav-item2" class="nav-item-wrap">Projects</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="nav-item-dropdown nav-item1-dropdown" style="display:none">
  <p>your action goes here</p>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.nav-wrap').hover(function() {
      $('.nav-item1-dropdown').show();
    });
    $('.nav-item1-dropdown').hide(); //use it wherever you need to hide it
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. What you have works but I want the div to disappear (be hidden) when I move the mouse away from the div. As it is now, it stays visible even when scrolling down the page. I need to be able to put mouse on the div and interact with its contents but have the div disappear on mouse out.

Thanks for your help.